# gulp partials causes browser sync errors

Tags: gulp, browser-sync, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

When I use partials on the scss structure, I have to deal with frequent browser sync error (like reloading forever). Notice that it is an intermittent error so it is not a common compiling problem (although it might be somewhat related) and it doesn't happen when I don't use partials. Also, I don't think it is project related or a gulpfile issue either, since it occurs with any project and I have tried more than one gulpfile structure. Anyway, you can check it out below:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var clean = require('gulp-clean');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

gulp.task('styles', function () {
    gulp.src('src/scss/app.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(autoprefixer())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('src/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('copy', ['clean'], function () {
    return gulp.src('src/**/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('clean', function () {
  return gulp.src('dist')
         .pipe(clean());
});

gulp.task('serve',function () {

    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: 'src/'
        }
    });

    gulp.watch('src/scss/*.scss', ['styles']);
    gulp.watch('src/**/*').on('change', browserSync.reload)

});

gulp.task('default', ['styles', 'serve']);
```

Comment: A couple of things that might help: (1) add a return statement in your 'styles' task and  (2) remove the second watch because it calls browserSync.reload which is already called at the end of the 'styles' task and you don't need to call it twice.  Let us know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks, Mark! Can you explain how do I add a return statement?

Comment: In your 'styles' task, add return right before gulp.src....  just like in the other tasks: So  : return gulp.src('src/scss/app.scss')

Comment: Looks like it worked! Awesome!

Comment: Great, I'll make it into an answer.  If it helped you please accept the answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things that might help: (1) add a return statement in your 'styles' task and (2) remove the second watch because it calls browserSync.reload which is already called at the end of the 'styles' task and you don't need to call it twice. So make these changes:

```
gulp.task('styles', function () {
  // added return below
  return gulp.src('src/scss/app.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(autoprefixer())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src/css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});
```

and the second watch is unnecessary and possibly a problem:

```
gulp.task('serve',function () {

  browserSync.init({
    server: {
        baseDir: 'src/'
    }
  });

  gulp.watch('src/scss/*.scss', ['styles']);
  //  remove below watch
  //  gulp.watch('src/**/*').on('change', browserSync.reload)

  gulp.watch("./*.html").on("change", browserSync.reload);

});
```

Comment: Unfortunately it was not a complete success. Actually, the side effect of the gulpfile edition was that the watch task stopped reloading when html files were modified.

Comment: That is an easy fix, I added a watch specifically for .html files.  I don't know your folder structure so may have to change the "./*.html" part to point to your html files, it is relative to the location of your gulpfile.js.